# why does the use of j (imaginary) generates a list of incremental values

Tags: python

I have the following code :

```
def sphere():
    #helper function to compute the coordinates of a unit sphere centered at 0,0,0
    # Create a sphere
    r = 1
    pi = np.pi
    cos = np.cos
    sin = np.sin
    phi, theta = np.mgrid[0.0:pi:20j, 0.0:2.0 * pi:20j]
    x = r * sin(phi) * cos(theta)
    y = r * sin(phi) * sin(theta)
    z = r * cos(phi)
    return (x,y,z)
```

The code works fine but I don't understand the part where `0.0:2.0 * pi:20j` 
obviously, it makes 20 subdivisions between 0 and 2pi but why?

what's the connection between the complex number and the generated list?

Comment: yes, `j`-literal denotes an imaginary number

Comment: Actually it is an *imaginary* number.

Comment: @zmbq yes good point. `20j` is an imaginary number, `1+20j` is a complex number.

Comment: @Zinki but this doesnt answer the question. I asked how come it generates a list of numbers in the interval, I changed the title and the question to clarify what i dont understand

Comment: The answer is [right there in the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html).

Comment: @NilsWerner Thanks! I thought it was a python thing, but now I see its a np.meshgrid thing.